NavigationView .navigationBarBackButtonHidden not working on the first run
Hokahey,
I've tried setting navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true), but it doesn't work for me as expected.
I'm trying to add a custom NavigationView Toolbar on the second screen. When I select the first Navigation Link and the second screen appears, the title is displayed as "Back Button Text." What the heck I didn't get?

Once you dismiss the second screen and select the navigation view again, the menu bar works as expected.

Here is my code piece. Same behavior on Xcode 15.4 (latest beta patch)
struct MyNavigationView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                NavigationLink {
                    SecondScreen(showCloseButton: true)
                        .navigationBarHidden(true)
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "tortoise.circle.fill")
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                            Text("SecondScreen")
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text("Touch for Info")
                                .font(.system(size: 10))
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading: Image(systemName: "trash.circle"),
                trailing:
                    NavigationLink(destination: {
                        SecondScreen(showCloseButton: false).navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    })
                
            )
            .navigationTitle("Master View")
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .accentColor(.pink)
        }
    }
}

struct SecondScreen: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var showCloseButton: Bool
    
    init(showCloseButton: Bool) {
        self.showCloseButton = showCloseButton
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Color.pink
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            if showCloseButton {
                VStack {
                    Button {
                        dismiss()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding(20)
                    }
                }
            }
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("Hello world!").foregroundColor(.white).font(.largeTitle)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    Button(action: {
                        dismiss()
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "arrowshape.backward.circle")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Text("Back")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                    })
                }
            }
            //.toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationTitle("Detail Title")
        }
        
        
    }
}


As mentioned in the answers and comments below NavigationView is deprecated.
The solution for this specific question is to change from
NavigationView to NavigationViewStack, but of course the rest should also be adapted to new NavigationViewStack.

Why are you using NavigationView it has been deprecated for years so has navigationBarItems

@loremipsum I'm migrating an older project. Most of the stuff worked, but you are right I should migrate this as well

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types

navigationBarBackButtonHidden also disables the back swipe so I don't think you should go down this route, why don't you just change the tint so the default back button is white?

try to add the .navigationViewStyle(.stack) modifier to your NavigationView or use NavigationStack instead of NavigationView`
